# Trouble specifying my tablename inside query because of dot notation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble specifying my tablename inside the following query.

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO db269193_crud.posts (post_title,description) 
  VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $description . "')";
```

The tablename is: db269193_crud.posts. I can't specify the table name as 'posts' because of my hostingprovider. They only allow me to specify it in conjunction with my databasename (which is db269193).

So the table name becomes: db269193(dot)posts. This dot however keeps lighting up in my editor as an incorrect syntax.

I need someone's help to tell me if I specified the table name correctly or if I have to use a variable to hide the dot notation like:

```
$tablename = 'db269193.crud'; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (post_title,description) 
VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $description . "')";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the entire name in backticks to escape it:

```
INSERT INTO `db269193_crud.posts` (post_title, description) 
  VALUES ('" . $title . "', '" . $description . "')
```

As for the rest of your statement, I would encourage you to use parameters instead of munging the query string.  By putting random strings in the query, you are just inviting syntax errors and SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't specify the table name as 'posts' because of my hostingprovider. They only allow me to specify it in conjunction with my databasename (which is db269193).

I pretty much doubt that as it would require DB changes which simply make no sense. I assume that it's your fault as you did not select DB to use in the first place. Check how you connect and ensure you provide DB name as well or at least you `mysqli_select_db()` or equivalent.

> $tablename = 'db269193.crud';

You can use backticks when name of table or column conflicts or is reserved word:

```
$tablename = '`db269193.crud`';
```

or

```
$tablename = '`db269193`.`crud`';
```

> $sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (post_title,description) 
>   VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $description . "')";

You are complicating simple strings with unnecessary concatentation. This will work and is less error prone:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (post_title,description) 
        VALUES ('{$title}','{$description}')";
```

however you are still seem to be vulnerable to sql injection here. I'd recommend switching to PDO.